# How a line could separate samples into 3 classes

Tags: neural-networks, terminology

I have troubling the understand linear separability issue. As far as I search on the web,

> To be linearly separable, you have to able to separate data with a
>   straight line for 2D, plane for 3D,

From that sentence, I understand that, I have to separate data with a **single** line if it is linearly separable. If I'm right, I wonder how could I separate my data into 3 different classes with a **single** line? It seems impossible?

Comment: Why do you think you can?

Comment: If I had 2 lines I could split it into up to 4 classes by making a "plus shape" or "x". If I had a Gaussian Mixture Model (aka single-element RBF) then I can make one or more components for each class and use as many total components as the data will support.

Comment: This is just the definition. *If* it is possible to separate classes with a straight line (in 2D), *then* your data are linearly separable. For >2 classes, you don't necessarily separate all classes from each other, but you can separate at least one from the rest in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a definition. If you can separate classes with a straight line (in 2 dimensions), the data are linearly separable.

If you have 3 classes in 2 dimensions, they are linearly separable if you can separate each class from all others singly, like this

```
a | b | c
```

or something similar. (This is sometimes called the "one versus all" strategy.)